# Excel file created by JAR file is being broken into smaller files despite not doing this inside of my IDE

Tags: java, sql, excel, export, println

I have a program which pulls data from an SQL query with the ability to create and write the data searched for to an excel file. This program can pull data from multiple queries, and sends that data to an excel file just fine for all of them except for one. The one that is giving me issues pulls about 350 results from its query, which is the largest amount pulled by an query. When I create the excel file in Eclipse, it just creates one excel file like intended. If I turn the program into a JAR file and create an excel file using that same query however, the excel file gets splits into about 5 different excel files, each holding roughly 50-60 results.

I've used the same basic code for other SQL queries and had it work just fine, this is the first time I've encountered this particular problem.

This is my write to excel file code. The data that is gotten from the SQL search is stored in 13 different lists, one list for each column in the sql search. The code takes todays date and time and adds it onto the file title. tableMade gets set to false when the excel file is first created, as the first thing added to the excel files is the column names. If it is not set to false, writeToExcel will add column names every time it adds data to the excel file.

```
public static void writeToExcel(String a, String b, String c, String d,
        String e, String f, String g, String h, String i,
        String j, String k, String l, String m){
    try{//sends data from toExcel to an excel file
        Date date2 = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss"); 
        String strDate = dateFormat.format(date2);//above creates title date/time
        String fileName = "Date "+ strDate + ".csv";//creates title: Data_For_yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm_SS
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName,true);//creates new excel file 
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fos);
        if(tableMade == false){
            pw.println(a + "," + b + "," +c+ "," +d+ "," +e
        + "," +f+ "," +g+ "," +h+ "," +i+ "," +j+ "," +k+ "," +l+"'"+m+ "\t");
            tableMade = true;//writes to excel file
        }

        pw.println(a + "," + b + "," +c+ "," +d+ "," +e
        + "," +f+ "," +g+ "," +h+ "," +i+ "," +j+ "," +k+ "," +l+"'"+m+ "\t");

        pw.close();

        System.out.println(fileName + " was created"); 
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
        System.out.println("Write to excel failed"); 
    }
}
```

This is the code for the button that calls writeToExcel. When pressed, this code is ran which create the excel file. The code iterates through each of the 13 lists at the same time, passing whichever value is currently being pointed at in each list as arguments to writeToExcel.

```
for(int i = 0; i < list1.size(); i++) {
                writeToExcel(list1.get(i), list2.get(i), list3.get(i), list4.get(i), list5.get(i),
                list6.get(i), list7.get(i), list8.get(i), list9.get(i), list10.get(i), list11.get(i),
                list12.get(i), list13.get(i)); 
            }
            excelAllowed = false; 
            tableMade = false;
        }
```

The expected output is 1 excel file holding all the queried date, however the actual output when running from a JAR file is 5-6 excel files each holding a chunk of the data.

Comment: Do note: a CSV is not an Excel file but a delimited, text file that Excel can read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Likely, your multiple CSV files have varying time stamps in file names since you define time stamps to seconds:

```
Date date2 = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss"); 
String strDate = dateFormat.format(date2);
```

With each pass of a very long loop, multiple seconds likely pass and hence multiple comma-separated values (CSV) files (not Excel files which are binary types –.xls, .xlsx, .xlsm, .xlsb) are generated. Adjust timestamp to minute or hour and all results may be contained in one CSV file.

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm");
```

Alternatively, define the file name outside the method and loop to use the time stamp when button is clicked:

```
Date date2 = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss"); 
String strDate = dateFormat.format(date2);              
String fileName = "Date "+ strDate + ".csv";

for(int i = 0; i < list1.size(); i++) {
     writeToExcel(...);                    // REMOVE fileName FROM INSIDE METHOD
}
```